# removing time stamp from a text file using sed script

Tags: bash, string, sed, awk

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/ HTTP/1.1" 200 169 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/.treeinfo HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Fedora HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Server HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Client HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/RedHat HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/CentOS HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/SL HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/directory.yast HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/current/images/MANIFEST HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/images/daily/MANIFEST HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/boot/platform/i86xpv/kernel/unix HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/platform/i86xpv/kernel/unix HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/STARTUP/XNLOADER.SYS HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/images/xen/vmlinuz HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/images/boot.iso HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/boot/boot.iso HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/current/images/netboot/mini.iso HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/install/images/boot.iso HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/ HTTP/1.1" 200 169 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/.treeinfo HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
1    27.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Fedora HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Server HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Client HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/RedHat HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/CentOS HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/SL HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/directory.yast HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/current/images/MANIFEST HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
```

How can I remove date from above logs using a sed script `[08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530]` like this there are many instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -r 's/\[[0-9]{2}\/[A-Z][a-z]{2}\/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} \+[0-9]+\]//g'
```

[**See it on Ideone**](http://www.ideone.com/9Ghh7)

Alternatively if there are no other occurrences of `[..]` in the input you can just do:

```
sed  's/\[.*\]//g'
```

Comment: why is double slash used at the end and in your script you have used curly braces {} why is that used?

Comment: You place the replacement text between `//`. In this case we want to replace it with nothing so there is nothing between them. `{x}` means x repetitions of the previous regex.

Comment: ohh thanks for your  explanation it cleared my doubt.If possible give some link for {x} I want to read.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -i.bak -ne 'print $_.gsub(/\[.*?\]/,"")' file
```

if you absolutely must use sed

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/\[.[^]]*\]//g' file
```

Comment: why is that double slash // there?

Comment: @Registered User, for substitution.

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern would be:

```
sed -e 's/pattern/replacement/' filename
```

With:

```
-e command

    Append the editing commands specified by the command argument 
    to the list of commands.
```

In your case, this could be e.g.:

```
sed -e 's/\[.*\]//' yourfilename.log
```

Note that `[.*]` will work correctly as long as you don't have additional `]` characters in a line.

Comment: Note that `sed` regex is greedy.

Comment: I want to know if I have an additional ] in line then what problem will [.*] cause?